# Can't understand functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn to react and I've made a basic todo list. Almost all aspects I understood, except one, which seems weird to me.

So in react we usually call functions like this : `button onClick = {btnClicked}`. In my todo list, when I want to remove a task, I need to call a function which calls another function. It looks like this:

```
div onClick = {() => removeItem(index)}> div
```

I don't understand why here we call a function that calls another function rather than just call `{removeItem}` function.

And if I write just

```
div Onclick = {removeItem}
```

the program doesn't act correctly ( it removes item, but not selected one).

Pls help

```
const Todo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    items: [],
    item: ""
  });

  const addItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (value.item == "") {
      alert("Please fill in the input");
    } else {
      setValue({
        items: value.items.concat(value.item),
        item: ""
      });
      console.log(value.items);
    }
  };

  const removeItem = index => {
    const list = value.items;
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setValue({ items: list });
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.TodoList}>
      <h1 className={s.Title}>Todos</h1>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={addItem} className={s.TodoForm}>
          <div className={s.Wrapper}>
            <h1>Add an item...</h1>

            <input
              type="text"
              name="item"
              value={value.item}
              onChange={e => setValue({ ...value, item: e.target.value })}
              placeholder="Type item here"
            />

            <button>Add</button>
            {value.items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <ul>
                  <li key={index}>
                    {item}
                    <div onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>
                      <i className="fas fa-times" />
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: if you do `onClick = {removeItem}` how will the function know which index value it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question! The `onClick` prop expects to be passed a function.

```
1. () => removeItem(index) is a function.

2. removeItem is also a function
```

*So why does it break?*

Your `removeItem` function requires an `index` argument. On click, the React library actually invokes the function you provided to `onClick` with an event object. Check it out by replacing your event handler with this and opening up your browser's developer console.

```
// Original
onClick = {() => removeItem(index)}

// New
onClick = {(event) => {
  console.log(event)
  removeItem(index)
}}
```

When you only pass it `removeItem`, React is actually invoking the function like so *instead of* with `index`

```
onClick={removeItem}

// What React does on click
removeItem(event)
```

This is why we create an anonymous function -- to invoke `removeItem` with what we expect on click.

```
// Ignores event object
onClick = {() => removeItem(index)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is actually pretty simple - you just need to understand what arguments your function is getting.

Consider this example:

```
<button onClick={myHandler}>Hello!</button>

const myHandler = (args) => {
    // args is the React event object - I can use the info in this object
    // if I need to
};
```

If you click the button, the `myHandler` function is called. But what is `args`? If you call the function like this, then `args` will be the React event object, which includes all sorts of interesting information like what element was clicked. For a simple button click, you often don't care about that - all you want to know is that the button was clicked.

Consider the following, though:

```
<ul>
    {this.state.listOfStuff.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id} onClick={(event) => myHandler(item.id)}>{item.name}</li>
    )}
</ul>

const myHandler = (args) => {
    // args is the item.id of the item that was clicked
};
```

In this case, I'm rendering a list of `<li>` elements, one for each item in my `listOfStuff`. When a user clicks on one of those list items, I need to know which one they clicked on. In this case, I don't care about the event (it's there in my `onClick` handler but I'm not using it - you can leave it out if you don't need it). But I do care very much about the ID of the item that was clicked. So in this case, when a user clicks and `myHandler` is called, `args` will equal the ID of the item that was clicked.